# How do I data bind a custom semantic ui dropdown to angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

There are two dropdowns where the second one gets the states for the first dropdowns selected country. The problem is that using semanticui's menu the `data-ng-model='selectedCountry'` value remains undefined when something is selected and my second dropdown remains empty. How can I get the `selectedCountry` from a semanticui menu. *(This works for me when I use `<select>` with `<option>'s`)*

## markup

```
<div ng-controller="loader">
    <div>
        <countrystate></countrystate>
    </div>
</div>
```

## controller

```
function loader($scope, $http) {
     var data = $http.get('Scripts/provinces.json');

     data.then(function (res) {
         $scope.Countries = res.data.countries;
         $scope.States = res.data.provinces;
     });

     data.catch(function (err) {
         console.log("error on : " + err);
     });

     $scope.getStates = function () {
         console.log("selected states: " + $scope.States);
         console.log("selected country " + $scope.Countries);

             var states = $scope.States.filter(function (state) {
                 return state.country === $scope.selectedCountry;
             });
             return states;

     }

    $scope.getFlag = function () {
        console.log(code.toLowerCase() + " flag");
        return code.toLowerCase() + " flag";
     }

 }
```

## directive

```
function countrystate($scope, $http) {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: false,
        template: `
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="CountryLabel">Country</span>
  <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
    <input data-ng-model='selectedCountry' />
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
    <div id="CountryMenu" class="menu">
      <div ng-repeat='country in Countries' class="item" id='{{country.name}}' value='{{country.code}}' onclick="$('#Country').val(this.id)"><i class="us flag"></i>{{country.name}}</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br />
<div class='input-group'>
  <span class='input-group-addon' id='StateLabel'>State</span>
  <select data-ng-model='selectedState' class='ui fluid search selection dropdown'>
       <option value=''>Please select a state</option>
       <option ng-repeat='state in getStates()' id='{{state.name}}' value='{{state.code}}' onclick="$('#State').val(this.id)">{{state.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
                        `,
        link: function(scope, element) {

            element.on('click', function() {
            });

            $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
            element.dropdown();

        }
    }
}
```

## note

I would like to use the semanticui menu dropdown so I could include the country image flags which I can't do with a regular html `<select>`

Comment: You can format a normal html select as a semantic dropdown. You just need to add `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();`. Maybe that will help

Comment: I want to use the image flags, but I cant use them if I use normal html select @DylanVanderBerg

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal did you find any solutions for binding your dropdown?

Comment: @cascadox yea i did, i took advantage of the class naming convention since it uses the class name to get the flag icons